# Scrolling in app when the Ipad is landscape and the app no longer fits in the size of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipados

Hello stackoverflow community,
I have just added the constraints to my iPad app and would now like that if you hold the iPad across that you can scroll the page, because not everything fits on a transverse page. If the Ipad is upright you should not be able to scroll (there everything fits).

How can I make that happen?

Edit:

I would like to be able to use landscape mode on my app, which I originally designed to be portrait only. For this I have already inserted all constraints so that the size etc. fits. Now, however, the page is so full that it no longer fits on the complete display in landscape mode. Now I would like to be able to scroll down and thus the complete page is on the display. How it looks at the moment in portrait and landscape format I have loaded into the attachment (do not wonder the app is in German).

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N94iT.jpg)

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwokV.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need a lot more information about what you've done so far, and what you are trying to do. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: I have now revised the description. I hope I have now considered everything ;-)

Answer (score 0):

add your views into `UIScrollView` and set its `contentsize`, you can thencontrol what should be visible or scrollable for both portrait and landscape

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you! And I can do that retrospectively? There are always only instructions on the Internet that you do at the beginning. In addition, the instructions never include texts. They only use a "view".